# No route to host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

Got this error when I run db:migrate for heroku from unix terminal.
I ping to [rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com](http://rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com) no data loss, but still I got error on migration. help me, thanks in advance.

> Error:       No route to host - connect(2) for "rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com" port 5000 (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
>   Command:     heroku run rake db:migrate
>   version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.28.1 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.1.5
>   Error ID:    e50a4e36c99b4e778791776f683c36e0**

Comment: Stacktrace for the error? Whatever you're expecting to be listening on port 5000 isn't.

Comment: Please refer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623814/heroku-run-rake-db-migrate-error-a-connection-attempt-failed

Answer (score 0):

Your internet does not allow you to reach it on port 5000. You can verify this by running:

`telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000`