# Heroku timeout awaiting process. Port 5000

Tags: heroku

I've been trying to run a django/heroku command:

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

But I'm getting the error "timeout awaiting process":

```
Running `python manage.py shell` attached to terminal... up, run.1720
 !    
 !    Timeout awaiting process
```

I've read that this is because the port 5000 is somehow closed or being used. This seems to be the problem because when I use my neighbor's internet, I don't get the error.

I don't know how to solve this, does Heroku offer a workaround?, Should I contact my internet provider?, Is there a Linux script or configuration that could be useful? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582860/heroku-run-console-get-timeout-awaiting-process

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I am trying to run `heroku run python manage.py shell` and doing `run:detached` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I conctacted Heroku's Support. The only solution to this problem is talking to the internet provider and requesting them to open the port 5000.

Comment: so it is not the problem from heroku. port 5000 open is for everyone? or does it demand to open new ?