# Deploying schema.rb to Heroku without CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, command-line-interface

I am using my university's ISP which blocks the 5000 port so I cannot `rake db:setup` to heroku. I recently ran `heroku rake db:reset` so that I can create a new database, but now I don't know how I can set it up. Is there any easy way to do this? I have seen lots of articles about `heroku pg:push`, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to put in for that. How can I setup my postgres database given that my 5000 port is blocked?

**Edit**: When running `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get the following error message: `ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000`

**Edit 2**: Here is the response to `dig rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com`

`

```
<<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49376
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com. 450 IN   CNAME   ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 604800 IN A 50.19.103.36

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  pdns1.ultradns.net.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  ns4.p31.dynect.net.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  pdns3.ultradns.org.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  u4.amazonaws.com.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  u3.amazonaws.com.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  ns3.p31.dynect.net.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  ns2.p31.dynect.net.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  pdns5.ultradns.info.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  u6.amazonaws.com.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  u1.amazonaws.com.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  ns1.p31.dynect.net.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  u5.amazonaws.com.
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  NS  u2.amazonaws.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
pdns1.ultradns.net. 1970    IN  A   204.74.108.1
pdns1.ultradns.net. 1970    IN  AAAA    2001:502:f3ff::1
ns3.p31.dynect.net. 69968   IN  A   208.78.71.31
pdns3.ultradns.org. 12753   IN  A   199.7.68.1
pdns3.ultradns.org. 43539   IN  AAAA    2610:a1:1015::1

;; Query time: 72 msec
;; SERVER: 152.19.240.8#53(152.19.240.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 28 19:50:08 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 500`
```

Comment: What's the error you get when you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`? Please add that to your post. Also check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#troubleshooting

Comment: I've looked at that page, but I am not able to get my IT department to open up the 5000 port, because it is a common place for Windows malware. Just added the result of my code when doing `heroku run rake db:migrate`. I just want to find a way to migrate my schema.rb. I have already tried `heroku run:detached rake db:setup` and it didn't work. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you run `dig rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com`  and show us the output.

Comment: Just added it to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of working on this, I found that this is simply a port block by my University. The best way to fix this if you are running into this problem and are at university is simply to go to a local coffee shop that offers free wifi. The port which the Heroku CLI relies on for running `rails console`, `rake db:migrate` and lots of other commands relies on you being able to maintain a connection through this port and will not work. Thanks to Cyzanfar for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I reading the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#troubleshooting) I found this:

> The heroku run command opens a connection to Heroku on port 5000. If your local >network or ISP is blocking port 5000, or you are
>   experiencing a connectivity issue, you will see an error similar to:
>
> ```
>   $ heroku run rails console
>     Running rails console attached to terminal...
>     Timeout awaiting process
> ```
>
> You can test your connection to Heroku by trying to connect directly
>   to `rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com` on port 5000 using telnet. A
>   successful session will look like this:
>
> ```
>   $ telnet
>     rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000 Trying 50.19.103.36...
>     Connected to ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 
>     Escape character >is '^]'
> ```
>
> If you do not get this output, your computer is being blocked from
>   accessing our services. We recommend contacting your IT department,
>   ISP, or firewall manufacturer to move forward with this issue.

What proxy are you using? You're most likely right about your ISP blocking port 5000 since `heroku run` does not do an HTTP call, it instead connects using TCP over port 5000 and uses its own protocol.

I found this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12883816/3307520) that mentioned getting around this issue by running the command in the the background:

```
$ heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

Then tail the logs to see what's happening:

```
$ heroku logs -p run.1 -t
```

Other than this I don't know of anything that can bypass the block on the 5000 port.